# How can I make a .bat file not exit when I run a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I put this code into a .bat script to run a file:

```
  powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\abc.ps1"
```

When the script finishes the window closes and I can't see the output. How can I make the window stay open?

Comment: Run your script directly in PowerShell. Then you don't need a batch file.

Comment: Why do you run a PS script in cmd?

Comment: I'd add `pause` on a new line.

Comment: My guess is that the point of running it in a batch file is to control execution policy without setting it in advance on the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want left in the window. Do you want a command prompt? If so use:

```
cmd /k powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\abc.ps1
```

Do you want a powershell window?

```
powershell -NoExit -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\abc.ps1
```